# Combining 2 UI as one main app window in python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I created a main app with a mdiArea for loading map graphics with Qt Designer *.ui and coded with pyQt4 using uic.loadUi() in python.
I also created a separate *.ui file and tested the dockWidget successfully in a separate python script file.
I wish to combine these 2 UI so that the main_app window will have the mdiArea widget on the left, while the dockWidget as the info_panel on the right.

I tried to load the *.ui file in the main app python, but ended up the dockWidget as a separate window when show().

Any advice to resolve this?
I hope I need not have to use Qt Designer to combine the mdiArea main_app UI with the dockWidget info_panel and load them as a single UI. ;P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on some software where every different pane is done as a separate. Ui file, so that they can be changed independently without requiring merges. It worked fine. Can you turn the map and dock parts into widgets, and then make a new "main window" ui, and then give that a layout and add the other two as child widgets to it?